# Error when upgrading from 6.22 to 7.8

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, upgrading

I upgraded my Drupal site from 6.22 to 7.8 (before that i had upgraded from 5.9 to 6.22).
After I start to run the update I had an error before it's started, apparently related to language:

Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
Original

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#039;TheBIgBrother.languages&#039; doesn&#039;t exist: SELECT * FROM {languages} ORDER BY weight ASC, name ASC; Array ( ) in language_list() (line 2513 of /mounted-storage/home106a/sub008/sc63415-EWDY/bigbrother-israel.co.il/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

Additional

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#039;TheBIgBrother.languages&#039; doesn&#039;t exist: SELECT * FROM {languages} ORDER BY weight ASC, name ASC; Array ( ) in language_list() (line 2513 of /mounted-storage/home106a/sub008/sc63415-EWDY/bigbrother-israel.co.il/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

Comment: Did the upgrade from 5.x to 6.x went smooth? Or did you immediately upgrade from 5.x to 6.x, and then to 7.x.

Comment: not smooth but it succedd in the end. and yes, i had the langusges warning also after my previous upgrade.

Comment: It could be something else then. But I would focus first on resolving the languages issue, and then once you have sorted that out, to move to the next warning/error.

Comment: i copied the table from another drupal 6 of my. now it's still "thinkung" before the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your languages table is missing. I hope you backed up your database before starting the update. If you have a backup, try restoring it and retry the update again.